# meaning of expression: 'type(uint).max'

Tags: solidity

In this code from Solidity documentation: inside the function 'add', what does the sentence '**type(uint).max**' mean?

Has something to do with this another kind of expression: 'address(this)'?

Is it some kind of cast?

[Library example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/contracts.html#libraries)

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.8 <0.9.0;

struct bigint {
    uint[] limbs;
}

library BigInt {
    function fromUint(uint x) internal pure returns (bigint memory r) {
        r.limbs = new uint[](1);
        r.limbs[0] = x;
    }

    function add(bigint memory _a, bigint memory _b) internal pure returns (bigint memory r) {
        r.limbs = new uint[](max(_a.limbs.length, _b.limbs.length));
        uint carry = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < r.limbs.length; ++i) {
            uint a = limb(_a, i);
            uint b = limb(_b, i);
            r.limbs[i] = a + b + carry;
            if (a + b < a || (a + b == type(uint).max && carry > 0))
                carry = 1;
            else
                carry = 0;
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            // too bad, we have to add a limb
            uint[] memory newLimbs = new uint[](r.limbs.length + 1);
            uint i;
            for (i = 0; i < r.limbs.length; ++i)
                newLimbs[i] = r.limbs[i];
            newLimbs[i] = carry;
            r.limbs = newLimbs;
        }
    }

    function limb(bigint memory _a, uint _limb) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return _limb < _a.limbs.length ? _a.limbs[_limb] : 0;
    }

    function max(uint a, uint b) private pure returns (uint) {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }
}

contract C {
    using BigInt for bigint;

    function f() public pure {
        bigint memory x = BigInt.fromUint(7);
        bigint memory y = BigInt.fromUint(type(uint).max);
        bigint memory z = x.add(y);
        assert(z.limb(1) > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type(X)` returns information about `X` type.

From the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#type-information):

> The following properties are available for an integer type T:
>
> - `type(T).min`
>   The smallest value representable by type T.
> - `type(T).max`
>   The largest value representable by type T.